# Probability question (High school level) involving permutations

Tags: probability, permutations

"An urn contains 20 parts and 5 of them are defective. Two parts are taken out of the urn randomly. What is the probability that: a) Both parts are good? b) Both of the parts are defective? c) One is good and the other one is defective? "

Please check the following answer regarding question a) :

The probability of both parts being good : 
$$\frac{{15 \choose 2}}{20 \choose 2} = \frac{105}{109} \approx 55,26 \%  .$$

Answer (score 2):

So there are a total of $20$ parts, with $5$ being good and $15$ being bad. For both to be good we need to choose from the good parts, so we get $$\frac{{15 \choose 2}}{20 \choose 2}.$$
For both to be bad we need to choose from the bad parts only, so
$$\frac{{5 \choose 2}}{20 \choose 2}.$$
And for exactly one to be good and one be bad, we choose exactly one from each,
$$\frac{{15 \choose 1}{5 \choose 1}}{20 \choose 2}.$$

Comment: Thank you for whole parts:)  i did it exactly same things